# Create branch from another branch with no committed history

Tags: git, github

I want to be clear as possible. For example,

Steps:

1. I'm working on branch1 and raised pull request.
2. While this branch under PR approval, I'm creating branch2 from branch1
3. Branch1 was approved and merged to develop branch
4. When I finished work with branch2 I'm raising PR. But when people look at my PR it has all history from branch1 as suppose to have.

Question: how can I (when I'm raising PR for branch2 and branch1 already merged)see difference only between develop and branch2 and not develop and (branch1 + branch2). Basically when people look at my PR for branch2 they have to look for branch1 as well because it was created from branch1, but branch1 was already merged.

Comment: can you merge develop with branch2?  if you get its merge commit in there it might omit the prior history

Comment: Rebase branch2 on develop after branch1 was merged?

Answer (score 2):

> When I finished work with branch2 I'm raising PR. But when people look at my PR it has all history from branch1 as suppose to have.

All you need to do is `git fetch upstream` (assuming `git remote -v` lists upstream as a reference to the original repo you have forked)
(it it does not, add it: `git remote add upstream /url/of/original/repo`)

Then you would rebase your `branch2` on top of upstream/master (which includes `branch1` code that was accepted and merged)

```
git checkout branch2
git rebase upstream/master
git push --force
```

The last command will override the history of `branch2` with the new updated one. Your existing PR for `branch2` will be automatically be updated.
And its diff history will show only `branch2` commits, no longer including `branch1` ones.

Comment: when I do `git fetch upstream` , error is `fatal: Could not read from remote repository.`. But when I check `git remote -v` it returns `origin  https://github.com/project.git (fetch)`. So, command `git rebase upstream/master` definitely will not work. But `branch1` was already merged and removed from github, can be it is an issue that it was removed. From your answer you saying that I need basically rebase `branch2` with master as my end goal?

Comment: Simply add upstream: `git remote add upstream https://url/of/original/repo`. You need to rebase `branch2` on top of `upstream/master` and force push `branch2` from there.